# prove conjunction of consecutive implications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$n\ge 2,p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n,p_{n+1}$ are statements.

Prove $(p_1\rightarrow p_2)\wedge (p_2\rightarrow p_3)\wedge ...\wedge (p_n\rightarrow p_{n+1})$
$\Rightarrow (p_1\wedge p_2\wedge p_3\wedge...\wedge p_n)\rightarrow p_{n+1}$

Base case:$(p_1\rightarrow p_2)\wedge (p_2\rightarrow p_3)\Rightarrow p_1\wedge p_2\rightarrow p_3$ (by truth table - omitted)

Assume $(p_1\rightarrow p_2)\wedge (p_2\rightarrow p_3)\wedge ...\wedge (p_{n-1}\rightarrow p_n)\wedge (p_n\rightarrow p_{n+1})$
$\Rightarrow (p_1\wedge p_2\wedge p_3\wedge...\wedge p_{n-1}\wedge p_n)\rightarrow p_{n+1}$

$[(p_1\rightarrow p_2)\wedge (p_2\rightarrow p_3)\wedge ...\wedge (p_n\rightarrow p_{n+1})]\wedge (p_{n+1}\rightarrow p_{n+2})$
$\Rightarrow [(p_1\wedge p_2\wedge p_3\wedge...\wedge p_{n-1}\wedge p_n)\rightarrow p_{n+1}]\wedge (p_{n+1}\rightarrow p_{n+2})$
$\Rightarrow (p_1\wedge p_2\wedge p_3\wedge ...\wedge p_n\wedge p_{n+1})\rightarrow p_{n+2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that we need an induction on the number $k$ of occurrences of $\land$ in the *conjunction*.

*(i) Basis* :

For $k=1$ you have already established it :

> $(p_1→p_2)∧(p_2→p_3) \vDash (p_1∧p_2)→p_3$

*(ii) Induction step* :

Assume it for $n$ :

> $((p_1→p_2)∧(p_2→p_3)∧ \ldots ∧(p_{n-1}→p_n)) \vDash (p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1})→p_n$

and prove it for $n+1$.

Abbreviate the last formula as $A_n \vDash B_n$.

We have clearly :

> if $A_n \vDash B_n$, then $(A_n \land S) \vDash (B_n \land S)$.

Now consider :

> $A_{n+1} := A_n \land (p_n→p_{n+1})$;

we have that $A_{n+1} \vDash B_n \land (p_n→p_{n+1})$, i.e :

> $A_{n+1} \vDash [(p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1})→p_n] \land (p_n→p_{n+1})$ --- **(*)**.

Now we can build this easy derivation (under the assumption $A_{n+1}$) :

*(a)* $(p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1}) \land p_n$ --- assumed

*(b)* $p_n$ --- from (a) by $\land$-elimination

*(c)* $[(p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1})→p_n] \land (p_n→p_{n+1})$ --- from **(*)**

*(d)* $(p_n→p_{n+1})$ --- from (c) by $\land$-elimination

*(e)* $p_{n+1}$ --- from (b) and (d) by *modus ponens*

*(f)* $[(p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1}) \land p_n] \rightarrow p_{n+1}$ --- from (a) and (e) by $\rightarrow$-introduction.

Thus :

> $A_{n+1} \vDash [(p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1}) \land p_n] \rightarrow p_{n+1}$

i.e.

> > if $A_n \vDash (p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots ∧p_{n-1})→p_n$, then $A_{n+1} \vDash (p_1∧p_2∧ \ldots \land p_n) \rightarrow p_{n+1}$.

Comment: You know(assume) that the implication is true for n and n+1 but how do you know that the premise('A_{n+1}') of the n+1 implication is true, making the conclusion of that implication true?(which you use in (c))

Comment: @user2008730 - in the *induction step* we assume that the property holds for $n$, i.e. that $A_n \vDash B_n$; then we assume $A_{n+1}$ and we prove $B_{n+1}$. In order to derive $B_{n+1}$ I've used in (c) the formula **(*)** that I have proved from $A_n \vDash B_n$ and propositional transformations.

Comment: Ok.  So from assuming $A_{n+1}$ to be true, you have $B_{n+1}$ true because if $A_{n+1}\models B_{n+1}$ and $A_{n+1}$ is true then $B_{n+1}$ must be true.  From there it is a simple derivation.  Thanks.